# ini4j reading registry values causes Java to crash

Tags: java, registry, ini4j

I have a couple of methods I've written here that read some values from the registry and populate some text fields in my Swing GUI.

Here is the first method:

```
public void loadRegValues() throws IOException {

    Scripts sc = new Scripts();

    //SET CONFIGURATION TAB TO COME FORWARD             
    setTabFolderSelection(1);

    //SET PREBACKUP AS FIRST SELECTED TAB
    setConfigTabFolderSelection(0);

    // [GLOBAL]
    setClientnameText(sc.readValueFromReg("[GLOBAL]", "clientname"));

    // [PREBACKUP]
    Boolean prebackupboolean = Boolean.valueOf(sc.readValueFromReg("[PREBACKUP]", "prebackup-enabled"));
    setPrebackupenabledSelection(prebackupboolean);

    // [OPENVPN]
    setOvpnprofileText(sc.readValueFromReg("[OPENVPN]", "ovpnprofilename"));

    setOpenvpngatewayipText(sc.readValueFromReg("[OPENVPN]", "remotegatewayip"));

    // [NETWORK DRIVE]
    setNetworkdriveletterText(sc.readValueFromReg("[NETWORK DRIVE]", "drive-letter"));

    setIpofshareText(sc.readValueFromReg("[NETWORK DRIVE]", "ipofshare"));

    setSharenameText(sc.readValueFromReg("[NETWORK DRIVE]", "sharename"));

    setShareusernameText(sc.readValueFromReg("[NETWORK DRIVE]", "shareusername"));

    setSharepasswordText(sc.readValueFromReg("[NETWORK DRIVE]", "sharepassword"));

    // [REGISTRY BACKUP]
    Boolean registrybackupboolean = Boolean.valueOf(sc.readValueFromReg("[REGISTRY BACKUP]", "registrybackup-enabled"));
    setRegistrybackupenabledSelection(registrybackupboolean);

    Boolean reghklmsoftwareboolean = Boolean.valueOf(sc.readValueFromReg("[REGISTRY BACKUP]", "hklm-software-enabled"));
    setHklmsoftwareenabledSelection(reghklmsoftwareboolean);

    Boolean regbackupcustompathboolean = Boolean.valueOf(sc.readValueFromReg("[REGISTRY BACKUP]", "reg-custompath-enabled"));
    setRegistrycustompathenabledSelection(regbackupcustompathboolean);

    setRegistrycustompathText(sc.readValueFromReg("[REGISTRY BACKUP]", "reg-custom-path"));

    // [FREEFILESYNC]

    setFfsbatchfilenameText(sc.readValueFromReg("[FREEFILESYNC]", "ffsbatchfile"));

    // [EMAIL]
    Boolean emailboolean = Boolean.valueOf(sc.readValueFromReg("[EMAIL]", "emailenabled"));
    setEmailenabledSelection(emailboolean);

    setGmailusernameText(sc.readValueFromReg("[EMAIL]", "gmailusername"));

    setGmailpasswordText(sc.readValueFromReg("[EMAIL]", "gmailpassword"));

    setClientemailText(sc.readValueFromReg("[EMAIL]", "clientemail"));

}
```

and here is the second one (It is in the class "Scripts"):

```
public String readValueFromReg(String valuecategory, String keyname) throws IOException
    {
        Reg reg = new Reg("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\KCBS\\Offsite Backup\\");
        Reg.Key cp = reg.get("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\KCBS\\Offsite Backup\\");
        Reg.Key valuecat = cp.getChild(valuecategory);
        String keyvalue = valuecat.get(keyname);
        return keyvalue;
   }
```

Whenever I run `loadRegValues()` it crashes my application. I'm using the ini4j API to read and write from the registry; I cannot work out why it would be causing it to crash.

EDIT:
Upon further findings, it would appear that the method of retrieving data from the registry using the tutorial the developer has provided on this page http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/WindowsRegistryTutorial.java.html doesn't work. The write feature works fine, the reading part however doesn't work even when using their provided example. I will contact the developer and try to get some help there.

Comment: Well, what is the specific error message, and at what line?

Comment: Kane, I've cleaned up a few (very common) issues in your question, and some older questions. Others folks have done the same for you earlier. It's not necessary to a) [include your tags in your title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66152/titles-should-the-most-relevant-tag-be-included-in-the-title), or b) [sign your posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: Okay, will keep that in mind @MichaelPetrotta, didn't know there was some particular etiquette that had to be followed when posting on here. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @LeorA, it doesn't make it past the line `setClientnameText(sc.readValueFromReg("[GLOBAL]", "clientname"));` It causes my swing GUI to go into "Not Responding" mode and I have to kill it. I've debugged that line but seeing as though it isn't throwing any exceptions in the Console I thought perhaps I am missing something obvious?